# Ubuntu - Apache ssl renew

Tags: android, apache, ubuntu, ssl

I have an Ubuntu VPS server from OVH with a SSL certificate bought from GoDaddy. In 30 days this certificate is going to expire and I need to renew it.
The server is hosting urls needed for few Android and iOS apps to work.

Once I renew my ssl certificate with goDaddy and I download the files, whats the best way to update my certificate without downtime or without the apps to crash?

What are the steps to update my ubuntu server with apache 2? I remember last year toke me hours to make my https connection to work. Do I have go through all the generation steps or I can just upload the new files?

Comment: I suppose, providing the new certificate's path to apache will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to generate a new CSR and go through the process again, unfortunately when you renew an SSL certificate, you're essentially just creating a new one.

However, as the configuration is in place, if you upload the new certificate files with the same name once generated and restart apache it should continue to work as expected.

You can also renew early, so you can do it out of hours/ test it at a more convenient time.

Comment: Ok Thanks.. So I will need just to do it in the night time. Do you know if I buy/renew the certificate early the old ones will still to work until the expiry date?

Comment: Yes they will :) Just don't overwrite the current certificate files :)